# How do you create a physical volume?

Tags: lvm

I'm having issues running `pvcreate`. I guess it's not recognizing my partition tables?

[image: picture of your terminal which you should replace with pasted text]

Comment: It looks like `/dev/sda1` is where your currently running filesystem lives - you won't be able to create an LVM PV out of that for the same reason that you can't delete your root partition.

Comment: You can not create a PhysicalVolume on a mounted partition, and you can not unmount the partition you booted from. I also think that creating a PhysicalVolume on a partition will wipe all the data in it, so you probably don't want to do this anyway.

Comment: @ByteCommander Add that information as an answer please. Yes, I know OP added one

Comment: Please use text instead of screenshot for terminal outputs

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. As ByteCommander has said, You must use an external drive to create a physical volume. You can not use a mounted hard drive. I set up my usb drive into my virtual machine and used gparted to make a new partition table. From there i could make the physical volume.